# Can't get my image to show

Tags: html, css, hover, position

I am having an issue with a page I'm building. I have a Js cycle with some outside-div-contained controls and the arrow_back class will show the hover state, but it won't show the normal state. The exact same code works for the arrow_forward button (including native & hover states.) Here is the css for it:

```
.arrow_back{
  width:42px;
  height:42px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:9999;
  left:8px;
  top:-83px;
}
.arrow_back:hover{
  background:url(../images/arrow_back_hover.png) no-repeat;
}
.arrow_forward{
  background:url(../images/arrow_forward.png) no-repeat;
  width:42px;
  height:42px;
  position:relative;
  top:-84px;
  right:-637px;
  z-index:9999;
}
.arrow_forward:hover{
  background:url(../images/arrow_forward_hover.png) no-repeat;
}
```

and the html:

```
<div class="image">
  <div class="slideshow">
    <img src="images/inside/cycle1.jpg" />
    <img src="images/inside/cycle2.jpg" />
    <img src="images/inside/cycle3.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="controls">
    <img src="images/arrow_back.png" width="42" height="42" class="arrow_back" />
    <img src="images/arrow_blank.png" class="arrow_forward" />
  </div>
```

If anybody could offer some advice. I've been staring at code all week so far, and my brain is a bit toasted. It's probably something very obvious I just need fresh eyes on.

Comment: There's no background image in `.arrow_back`.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the background image for the arrow_back class.

```
.arrow_back{
  background:url(../image/arrow_back.png) no-repeat;
  width:42px;
  height:42px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:9999;
  left:8px;
  top:-83px;
}
.arrow_back:hover{
  background:url(../images/arrow_back_hover.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Also, I removed the javascript tag since this doesn't really have anything to do with javascript.

Comment: Negative. I originally had the 'arrow_blank.png' file in the html, and the css added the background image. It works for the arrow forward, but not arrow backward. I then tried to add the image in the html for the arrow back, and it still doesn't show up. I thought it may be a position or z-index issue, but the dimenions show up in chrome's debugger, but it won't show the image.

***Nevermind, it was an error with our server. It didn't like the image file. Fixed it.

Comment: @MattZelenak Do you have an example site to show? I just made a jsfiddle and it seems to work for me in chrome. Images are not perfect but hover states function: http://jsfiddle.net/rFKyT/